# ReportViewer in WindowsForm. ReportViewer won't show

Tags: c#, reportviewer

Normally when I add a ReportViewer into a Windows form it will show up with the Reportviewer toolbar and everything, but now when im trying to do it in an existing program, it won't show up.
It just leaves me with a black Form. 
I've tried to do it programmatically, but I can't get it to work without that toolbar ! :p ( stupid me )

Any ideas what I could try, or what causes this??

Its just a simple report, where 3 strings should be shown, I have added them as parameters like this:

```
        ReportParameter p1 = new ReportParameter("NAME", Name_value);
        ReportParameter p2 = new ReportParameter("EMPLOYEE_ID", EmployeeId_value);
        ReportParameter p3 = new ReportParameter("COMPANY", Company_value);
        reportViewer3.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ProcessingMode.Local;

        reportViewer3.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "Report1.rdlc";
        reportViewer3.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"C:\Users\MGRU\Desktop\projects\EmpKeyCard\EmpKeyCard\EmpKeyCard\Report1.rdlc";

        reportViewer3.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { p1, p2, p3 });
        reportViewer3.ShowParameterPrompts = true;
        reportViewer3.RefreshReport();
```

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the relevant code you have ? It will surely help other SO members to answer your question, thanks.

Comment: I have an Empty form, and for now I just want to Drag and drop the ReportViewer, but It doesent show on the form..

Comment: What versions of Visual Studio and report viewer are you using? I have had a similar problem with 2012 and report viewer 10 working in .net 3.5

Comment: VS 2013, and report viewer 10.

Comment: Could try the same 'fix' as me. With that combination I couldn't add a report viewer in the designer. However I had VS 2010 on my computer which worked perfectly. Not an ideal situation, but one I have been working with since. If you are not bound to older versions of .net, maybe you could try with report viewer 11

Comment: I think 11 worked for me in 2012. But I need to use .net 3.5 so I am currently going back to VS2010 whenever I need to add a report viewer. If you are desperate it may be worth a try with the express copy

Answer (score 0):

this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();

It is important to have for the report to display. The culprit for getting a blank page could be this.

Answer (score 0):

Download and install MICROSOFT® REPORT VIEWER 2012 RUNTIME from this link https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=35747 
  This solved my same problem.